# Problem displaying firebase database content on my android studio application

Tags: java, firebase

I have this code which is supposed to fetch a comment from my database and display it, the comment is correctly stocked on my database but when I try to retrieve it, it won't display in my app. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
public CommentAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<Comment> listComment) {
    this.mContext = applicationContext;
    this.mData = listComment;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CommentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_comment, parent, false);
    return new CommentViewHolder(row);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentViewHolder holder, int position) {

   // Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getUimg()).into(holder.img_user);
    holder.txt_name.setText(mData.get(position).getUname());
    holder.txt_content.setText(mData.get(position).getContent());
    holder.txt_date.setText(timestampToString((Long) mData.get(position).getTimeStamp()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class CommentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView img_user;
    TextView txt_name, txt_content, txt_date;

    public CommentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //img_user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_user_img);
        txt_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_username);
        txt_content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_content);
        txt_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_date);
    }

}

private String timestampToString(long time) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
    String date = DateFormat.format("hh:mm", calendar).toString();
    return date;
}
```

Comment: What does `mData.get(position).getUname()` inside `onBindViewHolder` return?

Comment: @AlexMamo The name of the user who sumbmitted a comment

Comment: What is the database you're using? Firestore or the Realtime Database? Please show us the structure and the way you're reading that data.